# Swift 4 - Saving UIView to UIImage cuts image

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to save a UIView with components in it to an image and save that image the the Photos.
For that I am using the following code

```
let image = scrollContent.asImage() //UIImage(view: scrollContent)

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self,#selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
```

and one of these two extensions (Second one is better).

```
extension UIImage {
convenience init(view: UIView) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
    view.layer.render(in:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    self.init(cgImage: image!.cgImage!)
}
}

//Or

extension UIView {

func asImage() -> UIImage {
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
    return renderer.image { rendererContext in
        layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
    }
}
}
```

My Problem is that sometimes this code saves only a cut version of my image to the photos. But the view is displayed completely. How can that be ? Is there a max size or something ?

Comment: tried the more extended method UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, false, UIScreen.main.bounds)?

Comment: No ! Will try it tomorrow and report. Thanks for the answer =)

Comment: I made a mistake, should be UIScreen.main.scale, not .bounds.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't help. Can it be caused by the view being in a UIScrollView ?

Comment: Yeah highly likely. You should not use the UIScrollView for the image but its contentView

Comment: Do you mean a specific property of the UIScrollView or just the view I use inside the ScrollView ?